# client.channels.get(id).send() not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So a discord bot I'm creating has a twitch notifications, and it uses snekfetch to create a looping request function. On the return of the function I have `client.channels.get(id).send(embed)` however it doesn't message the channel id which I've given it.

```
const api = `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_login=${streamer}`;

  snekfetch.get(api).set('Client-ID', "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX").then(r => {

    if (r.body.stream === null) {

      setInterval(() => {

        snekfetch.get(api).then(console.log(r.body))

      }, 30000);

    } else {
        const embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(
        `${r.body.data.user_name} is live on Twitch`,
      )
        .setThumbnail(`http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/live_user_${streamer}-500x500.jpg`)
        .addField('Views', `${r.body.data.viewer_count}`, true)

      return bot.channels.get(XXXXXXXXXXXX).send("TEST");
    }
  });
```

I have named my client bot so instead of client.channels it's bot.channels

It should in theory send the TEST message to whatever channel id I give it, however instead I get an error.

```
(node:62565) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at /Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/HelperBot/main.js:61:50
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
(node:62565) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:62565) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Ensure you're using a string for the ID, not a number. IDs are [Snowflake](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake)s.

Comment: What's the format of value behind `XXXXXXXX`? Can you give an example but with changed ID (change few numbers to different ones but don't remove quotes or any other characters). If you don't have quotes, what slothiful suggested might be the case.

Answer (score 1):

your error has to do with that not all channels are text channels. Before you can send a message it has to be sure it can. so you could check if that's the case with the function .isText() when you have checked that it is the type should change to text channels which are dm text and news at this moment. those have the .send function

Answer (score -2):

The error said it can't find the `.send("Test")` function of something that is not defined.

So the error come from `bot.channels.get(XXXX)`
bot.channels return a collection. If you search a specific item of this collection. You need to use `.find` and not `.get`

More info about .find here : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find

Comment: Straight from the method in the docs: "All collections used in Discord.js are mapped using their `id` property, and if you want to find by id you should use the `get` method. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) for details."

Comment: Like @slothiful said, get and find doesn't return a collection. It queries what ever is inside the method 'from the collection'.